# Domain Join Assistance: Account Already Exists

Tags: vbscript, scripting, active-directory

I am trying to get a domain join VBScript to work, however am having issues with computer accounts that "already exist".

It is set to use the current name of the computer and join the domain. Every time it tries to join the domain, it usually comes up stating that the account already exists on the domain. Now, I have removed the AD account and already let replication take place for a couple days now. Every time the script is ran, it continues to say that it already exists.

I tried to do an if statement that if it said the account already existed, only do the JOIN_DOMAIN part of it. It then says Access is Denied.

Not really sure where to go from this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I posted the code. I didn't include the variables, but they're there.

```
Const JOIN_DOMAIN = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE = 2
Const ACCT_DELETE = 4
Const WIN9X_UPGRADE = 16
Const DOMAIN_JOIN_IF_JOINED = 32
Const JOIN_UNSECURE = 64
Const MACHINE_PASSWORD_PASSED = 128
Const DEFERRED_SPN_SET = 256
Const INSTALL_INVOCATION = 262144

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName

Set objComputer = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" & _
    strComputer & "'")

ReturnValue = objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup(strDomain, _
    strPassword, strDomain & "\" & strUser, strOU, _
    JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE)
```

I have confirmed that this also happens with brand new names along with computers that have never been on the domain before. It doesn't happen for every single one - so far every 1/5 brand new computers and names that have never been used on the domain before, this script has failed for some reason.

Comment: Are the credentials valid and does the account have permission to join a computer to the domain and put the computer account in the given OU? Does the issue persist if you use `netdom` or PowerShell instead of VBScript? Does the error occur every time, or one time out of five? Does the eventlog (local and on the DC) say anything about this?

Comment: The `strDomain` isn't defined.

Comment: @Ansgar Issue persists with PowerShell - haven't tried VBScript. I'm thinking it may be permissions-based, however I have had no issue using the account given any time in the past. I actually have an image about 2 years old that works without issue, adding it to the OU I specify, same credentials and all. I haven't checked the eventlog just yet.

Comment: @Noodles - It is. I didn't post the variables.